# Fetching specific data from firebase array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I have this collection:

[image]

I am trying to only get the groupID's in the array there are like 3 of them, but I tried a for loop in a for loop but it keeps returning undefined. Where am I going wrong?

```
fire.firestore().collection('userEvents2').doc(fire.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
    groups: groupsList
})


for (let i = 0; i < groupsList.length; i++) {
    const key = "";
    for (key in groupsList[i]) {
        console.log(key.groupID)
      }
    
  }
```

Comment: Hi @emilysmyth , could you please include how you get the `groupsList` for us to be able to reproduce the `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the loop is trying to run before groupList is resolved?

Is that the complete code?
Are you storing groupList in a variable like `let groupList = groups.groupList;` ?